# internal routing and bottom bracket sleeve

Tags: bottom-bracket, cable-routing

I was wondering regarding the sleeve that comes with the bottom bracket I got from chris king.
My frame has internal routing, that I believe entails that cables should go through the bottom bracket. However, to me it seems that the sleeve takes up all the space there, I don't see how any cables should go in there? Is the only way to do it is by removing the sleeve? is it okay to remove to sleeve? I add here some photos. With/without the sleeve. And also, what seems to be an opening just below the bottom bracket, perhaps for water? Added a photo without its cover as well.

Thank you very the assistance and have a great week
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: from the picture, it looks like the internal diameter of the bearing is larger than the typical 24mm that you find on most Shimano/SRAM cranks. It you are trying to fit a 30mm axle into a standard BSA BB, it's possible that there's just not enough space for the cables and the crankset.

Comment: Hey thanks @Renaud. I see. you mean that even if I were to remove the sleeve, it might not help in my case since the axle is 30mm? (which it is).

Comment: If there's enough space, not sure there's much you can do, except changing the crank or choose another route (which doesn't seem feasible). I would not remove the sleeve, because in this case there will be a direct contact between the axle and the cable, which become a wear point.

Comment: Apparently there is another route (thankfully), I just realised that now. It is not clear in the photos, but basically, below the bottom bracket, where there is an opening that is sealed with a cover and a screw- if you open it, it gives you access to the area below(!) the bottom bracket, but still internal. and there is access to move cables in there below the bracket. seems like it solves my problem thanks.

Comment: I will still be curious to understand for the future, whether a sleeve can be removed, if that was the only option (assuming the axle was not 30mm). I can see your point of view - recommending not to do it, since there will be a direct contact between the axle and cables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sleeve prevents the cables and hoses from rubbing against the crank spindle. You’re spinning at 70-90 rpm for hours on end. Eventually, you would wear through the spindle, and this would be bad. It might not cause an immediate accident, but you now need to replace the whole crankset unless it’s a modular system that lets you change spindles.

In at least some frames, the hose goes out of the frame, routes around the bottom or the top of the BB, then it goes back in at the chainstay. I can’t see any evidence for this, but the photos might not be at the right angle.

First step would be check with the manufacturer. They might not have intended for the bike to have a 30mm spindle. Now, this isn’t a problem on a lot of bikes, but that looks like a BSA shell, and they can take 30mm spindles but they were not really designed with that diameter in mind. Alternatively, the manufacturer may say there’s room for one hose but no shift cable - I assumed that in the question you meant hoses, but I guess I don’t know for sure. If that frame was not designed for internal routing at all - and there would be various stops on the outside where you ziptie the rear brake hose plus the shift cable and housing - then you would need to use an electronic groupset.

Comment: The first paragraph in @Weinwen Ng's answer is critical. Don't event think about riding with internally routed cables and BB sleeve removed. You will damage both cable and crank axle much faster than you think.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate your answers.